# KMP search: Can a shift by partial match prefix by non-suffix match lead to exact match?

Tags: strings, string-matching, exact-string-matching

Consider the following step where 'abaab', upon failed mismatch, 'ab' the prefix is followed by aligning at 'ab' the suffix. What confuses me is the reason for being able to discard the possibility of a case where 'ab' may be inbetween the two also that might lead to a correct match. So why is it theoretically impossible to have such a case? I would appreciate, if possible, an intuitive answer.

[image: Shift]

Thank you.